# No error when stepping through in debug mode but AttributeError otherwise

Tags: python, pathlib

Example code

```
from pathlib import Path

for f in Path(<dir>).iterdir():
    print(f._str)
```

I'm using it to pass to a function but not even this works when running normally or debug without a breakpoint. Using a breakpoint and stepping through it prints everything out just fine (`_str` is the total path!

Comment: I think you want `f.path` or maybe just `f`, not `f._str`, which should be the same as `str(f)`

Comment: No. That is not the case.

Comment: Humor me and try `print(f)` instead

Comment: Calling the print function on an object invokes the `__str__()` method for that object (if it was defined). So, `print(f)` is the same as `print(f.__str__())` or `print(str(f))`

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you are trying to do or print, but, yes, this throws an AttributeError. Probably because, well, `._str` is not an attribute of the `Path` class.

```
from pathlib import Path

for f in Path('/tmp').iterdir():
    print(f._str)

AttributeError: _str
```

This does print the full path.

```
for f in Path('/tmp').iterdir():
    print(f)

/tmp/com.apple.launchd.0CERUFd5eE
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JLaC2VPWPS
/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jyIh6h3f8I
```

If you want just the names of the files & directories, do `print(f.name)`

Comment: `_str` must be an attribute of the `Path` class, as evidenced by the fact that it works when stepping through, and by using one's eyes while in the debugger.

Comment: It might be injected into the class by the debugger itself because it isn't [part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: You're talking over my head here (I don't mean that negatively). What do you mean? Looked at the docs myself but it seems like they don't have everything for the `WindowsPath` object (could be wrong though).

Comment: I'm just guessing that at run-time of the debugger, the `._str` attribute is added to all the objects for easier debugging. It probably maps to `__str__()`